# Get node translation from JSON:API

Tags: nodes, i18n-l10n

I have over a dozen languages on my site and we use Json:Api since it's a decoupled drupal.
Problem is that I can't figure out how to get the translated node values from the Json:Api response.

The Json:api url is as follows:

```
https://mysite.com/jsonapi/node/{bundle}/{uuid}?include=field_image,field_taxanomy
```

And it returns all the data with the relationships for the two extra fields included, but how do I request the data for a translation??? (almost each node has been translated into each of the available languages)

Comment: Have you tried simply (e.g.) `https://mysite.com/fr/jsonapi/node/{bundle}/{uuid}?include=field_image,field_taxanomy`. If not that, replace with whatever language negotiation method you're using in the Drupal site

Comment: @Clive Well i feel stupid :) Thanks. That's the correct answer